# open and Save files at password protected network shared computer through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to open and save a file at location 10.42.X.X. How can I write code to give a username and password to access this IP machine?

```
objPPTX.Presentations.Open "\\10.42.x.x\Reports_New\PRESTIGE LEVEL\Pending IMs\Pending IMs Report Template_Dont 

ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "\\10.42.X.X\Reports_New\PRESTIGE LEVEL\Pending IMs\Pending IMs.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the location/drive first and then pass the username and password variables like so

```
Dim objNetwork as Object, persistent as Boolean
persistent = false
set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "drivelettergoeshere:", ""\\10.42.x.x\............", persistent, "username", "password"
```

Comment: Glad I could help!